# Bug while error handling Firebase Authentication with swiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

This is my AuthViewModel:

```
@Published var userSession: User?
    @Published var currentUser: AppUser?
    @Published var signupError: Error?
    @Published var loginError: Error?
    
    static let shared = AuthViewModel()
    
    init() {
        
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        fetchUser()
    }
    
    func fetchUser() {
        guard let uid = userSession?.uid else { return }
        USER_COLLECTION.document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, _ in
            guard let user = try? snapshot?.data(as: AppUser.self) else { return }
            self.currentUser = user
        }
    }
    
    
    func registerUser(withEmail email: String, password: String) {
        
        
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                self.signupError = error
                print("error")
                return
                
            }
            
            
            
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            let data: [String: Any] = ["uid": user.uid, "email": user.email ?? ""]
            USER_COLLECTION.document(user.uid).setData(data) { err in
                
                self.userSession = user
                self.fetchUser()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
    func login(withEmail email: String, password: String) {
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                self.loginError = error
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            self.userSession = user
            self.fetchUser()
        }
    }
```

I have 2 published variables which are updated every time there is an error in their respective functions. However, when I click the 'sign up' button the first time with invalid credentials, I don't get an alert. I have to click it the second time to see the alert. Attached below is the code from the sign up view SwiftUI button with action and label. The same applies to the login view.

```
Button {
    authViewModel.registerUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
                           
    print("called")
        if let error = authViewModel.signupError {
            alertTitle = "Error signing up!"
            alertMessage = error.localizedDescription
            alertShowing = true
            print(alertShowing)
        }
    print(alertShowing) 
    } label: {
    CustomAuthButton(text: "Sign Up")
}
```

Below is the code attached to the sign up view (navigation view):

```
.alert(alertTitle, isPresented: $alertShowing) {
    Button("OK") {
        authViewModel.signupError = nil
    }
} message: {
    Text(alertMessage)
}
```

Attached below is the code for registering a user. I'll put the result of those print statements below.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.signupError = error
                print("error")
                return
            }
            
        }


called
```

false
2022-07-06 12:59:54.424510+0530 InfoMax[62528:2751506] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
error

As you can see, error is being printed late. When I tap the button the second time, it is printed before, so I get the alert.

Comment: Change `try?` to `do try catch`. Also, make sure when you update the `@Published` variables you do it on the main queue. Hard to help more Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Put a lot of `print` statements figure out what is being called and what is now such as when the `guard` forces a `return`

Comment: I have updated the question and attached the print statements and when they are printed after pressing the button.

Comment: Your code is far from a reproducible example. The print statements are for you. So when you run the code you can see what is going on since we can help you . That boring SLL message isn’t an error. Google it and you will see everybody is getting that it I doesn’t do anything so you can ignore because it only happens on simulator. Based on what you are saying I think I your issue may be that you are misunderstanding asynchronous code.

Comment: yeah I know that the message isn't an error I just wanted to show you when the error print statement is being called. Although you may be right about me not understanding asynchronous code, why is it that when I click the button the second time, the alert shows perfectly well?

Comment: Ignoring errors is not good practice `getDocument { snapshot, _` using "_". Please use `error` in that position and then capture the error if there is one. Not saying there is, but error messages can be *very revealing*! Also, `DispatchQueue.main.async` is unneeded in Firebase closures are UI calls are always on the main thread, networking is on a background thread. You mention you click a `signup` button. What function does that call? Also, the code is unclear; why this `self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser` followed by `fetchUser`? If you have a currentUser, why fetch one?

Comment: The fetchUser is to create an instance of the User class so I can use it in the app. I don't want to call the user from firebase all the time. I have a custom user object.